# The effect of inaccurate eyeglasses on development of myopia

Tags: myopia-nearsightedness

Suppose a person has myopia and requieres a basic correction of −6 dioptres to restore normal distance vision. Instead, he wears weaker eyeglasses, say -5.5 or -5. Can this fact have any effect (positive or negative) on the further development of his myopia? I.e., is the myopia more/less likely to worsen as a result of wearing weaker-than-needed eyeglasses?